# IIS Manager crashes when I try to open the node for my server

Tags: windows-7, windows, iis, iis-7

I have a Windows 7 x64 with PowerShell 5.0 and IIS7.

IIS Manager crashes when I try to open the node for my server with the following error with the following error:

```
IISMANAGER_CRASH

IIS Manager terminated unexpectedly.

Exception:System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: The method or operation is not implemented. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Management.Tools.PowershellHost.NoConsolePSRawUserInterface.get_BufferSize()
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostRawUserInterface.get_BufferSize()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ConsoleLineOutput.get_ColumnNumber()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.OutCommandInner.ProcessOutOfBandPayload(FormatEntryData fed)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.OutCommandInner.ProcessPayload(FormatEntryData fed, OutputContext c)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.OutCommandInner.ProcessObject(PSObject so)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.OutCommandInner.ProcessRecord()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FrontEndCommandBase.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoStepItems(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.CommandWrapper.Process(Object o)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.SubPipelineManager.Process(PSObject so)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.OutputManagerInner.ProcessRecord()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FrontEndCommandBase.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()

Process:InetMgr
```

I found a couple pages on the web [link1](http://forums.iis.net/p/1214661/2081742.aspx?IS%20Manager%20terminated%20unexpectedly%20) and [link2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9d445c21-22ee-45ee-80fe-1d39a3b40304/appfabric-crashes-iis-manager-when-powershell-4-is-installed-server-2008-r2-sp1?forum=velocity).  I tried installing the [Upgrade Readiness Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3132) and rebooted, but it didn't help.  Any ideas?

Comment: The first thing you should do is add/remove IIS.  Why are you running a tool to help solve Windows Update problems?

Comment: I am running the tool because it fixed the user's problem in link2.

Comment: You are not running it on a AppFabric server nor as you using Powershell 4.0, the problem in your links, are not cause by the samething.

Comment: Removed iis, rebooted, added it back.  Same problem.  The error message doesn't mention AppFabric, but it does mention Powershell.  I have websites that use AppFabric.

Comment: downgrade PS from 5 to 4, does it fix it?